# Unexpected errors in vba (Type mismatch and Invalid Procedure,Call or Argument)

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I have a pretty simple model which runs multiple times; each time it recalculates a sheet to generate result and then pastes those results onto a new sheet, so that at the end I have a large dump of data.

If I set it to run less than c.232000 (each simulation only takes a fraction of a second) it runs fine, no errors at all.

When I try to run more than c.232000 sims, I end up getting two "Type mismatch" error boxes followed by an "Invalid Procedure,Call or Argument" error box. Once I click okay on these three errors the code resumes and runs until the end.

Does anyone know the possible cause of these errors as I see no difference between sim 232000 and 232001? 
I am considering using "On Error/Resume Next", but I need to know where the cause is; whether it's the Activesheet.calculate line or the copy and past lines.

```
Sub simdump()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("Dump").Select
Range("G1").Value = Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
Range("A3:G500000").ClearContents
Range("I3:IY500000").ClearContents

Sheets("Cost").Select
Range("E2").Value = 1

Dim nScenarios As Integer
Dim simMultiplier As Integer

nScenarios = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Scenarios").Range("D:D")) - 1
simMultiplier = Sheets("Cost").Range("D51").Value

For k = 1 To nScenarios

Sheets("Scenarios").Select
Range(Cells(k + 2, 1), Cells(k + 2, 3)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Loans").Select
Range("N4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("Scenarios").Select
Cells(k + 2, 4).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Cost").Select
Range("E6:CZ6").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Loan Backup").Select
Range("K2:K250").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]-Scenarios!R" & k + 2 & "C5"
ActiveSheet.Calculate


For n = 1 To simMultiplier
    Sheets("Cost").Select
    Range("E53:IT352").ClearContents

    For l = 1 To 3
        Sheets("Loan Backup").Select
        Range(Cells((l - 1) * 100 + 2, 1), Cells(l * 100 + 1, 11)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Loans").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Sheets("Correlation").Calculate

        Sheets("Cost").Select

        For m = 1 To 300

            ActiveSheet.Calculate

            Range("E46:CZ46").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Cells(52 + m, 5 + (l - 1) * 100).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Next m
    Next l
    Range("D53:IT352").Copy
    Sheets("Dump").Select
    Cells(300 * ((n - 1) + (k - 1) * simMultiplier) + 3, "I").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

Next n
Cells(300 * (k - 1) * simMultiplier + 3, "G").Value = Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

Sheets("Scenarios").Select
Range(Cells(k + 2, 1), Cells(k + 2, 5)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Dump").Select
Cells(300 * (k - 1) * simMultiplier + 3, "B").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Range(Cells(300 * (k - 1) * simMultiplier + 3, "A"), Cells(300 * k * simMultiplier + 2, "A")).Value = k

Next k

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please paste your code in your post?

Comment: I have seen this kind of behaviour before happen, if you do not reset your variables or deallocate them before re-inizializing them. You're probably just missing `Set yourVariable = Nothing` before using them again or something similar (difficult to say without seeing any code).

Comment: What line(s?) are you getting the error on?

Comment: That's part of my problem. When the errors pop up I'm not able to click into the code to see which line it is on.

Comment: Can print screen the error message and post here?

Comment: The errors are two type mismatch boxes and then one invalid argument box. I would post screens, but the errors generally occur over an hour into the run.

Comment: What happened to the variable declaration section? Can you update your code with that as well? Otherwise nobody would know what data types your variables are. Further I suggest you to do a step by step debug run with breakpoints. Then you will have a clue where code breaks.

Comment: More code included in my question. Is there a way to stop the code on error and let me explore it, as I can't debug step by step...the error occurs over an hour into the run and even with breakpoint runs it would still need me to click "play" over 2000 times.

Comment: `.the error occurs over an hour into the run` : What does that supposed to mean? When you write a code, you should be able to debug compile it and go step by step. Why can't you reduce your loop iterations to 2 or 3 a manageable number? I still don't see your full code/macro. Please post it from the point it says `Sub` till the `End Sub`

Comment: My full code is above. It was literally only missing the end sub line. I explained in the second paragraph of my question that the errors do not occur when iterations are less than 232000. This is my main issue. I know how to debug a short bit of code, but can't go step by step in this case because the error only happens when I have over 232000 iterations.

Comment: What's the version of your Excel/MS Office?

Comment: 2010 version 14.0.6129.5000 (32-bit)

Comment: Still waiting for your print screen. What is this sim 232000? Is it iteration?

Comment: Check your code:  Cells(300 * ((n - 1) + (k - 1) * simMultiplier) + 3, "I").Select          Will it exceed 1,048,576 row limit?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it has to do with the limits on size of a worksheet. 
Limits on worksheet size are:  1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns [source](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).
So if 232000 iterations all produce 5 values placed in one column you exceed the numbers of rows.

And to check whether it has to do with the amount of iterations, or the specific iteration you could start your run not at 1 but at a number close to were your error usually occurs, so that it only runs for a few minutes.